# Alternative expressions to describe "rich experience"

Tags: phrases, expressions

I use "rich experience" often, but would like to use more precise expression.
i.e

> I have rich experience in mobile application development and have
>   built more than 8 iOS apps for the last 3 years.

Not sure whether it is appropriate, and please let me know better solution if any.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to consider what experiences and what was gained from the experience.        .......it would only be then you could be more precise. You need to edit the question to include the sort of experiences that need description.

Comment: Just updated it, can you please review it?

Comment: What does "more precise" mean in this context? Also, what have you looked up and found in your own research? Do you mean *extensive experience*? Do synonyms of *extensive* help?

Comment: More appropriate

Comment: "More appropriate" is entirely subjective. How are you going to judge what is more appropriate? Please make the question objective.

Comment: I am not convinced that there is an issue with objectivity here,. given the specific example offered. I will not carry the issue to "extensive men" or "extensive ice cream" as appropriate terms for "rich men" or "rich Ice cream". The OP was seeking a "better" (necessarily subjective) way of expressing a thought. That thought involved a word that cannot be easily interchanged with another (rich). in the given context. If English users  come to deciding "better" is negatively subjective, then English will be the loser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rich experience in technology parlance is reserved to User Interfaces and general aesthetic of software/hardware

Something on the lines of

> The Facebook application gives a rich experience to the end user

If you want to denote that you have experience in some field.
You may use relevant, skilled or as previously answered : extensive

I have seen the relevant word used on Curriculum Vitaes

Answer (score 3):

> I have rich experience in mobile application development and have built more than 8 iOS apps for the last 3 years.

Yes, "rich experience" is not used a great deal in this context.

> I have extensive experience in mobile application development

Is more common. As a single word to replace "rich" , "extensive" seems to work well.